# Javascript not recognizing new line

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js

I am posting some details into my Nodejs backend using ajax request and creating a string with multiple lines. To do this I am doing something like:

```
 changeString = req.body.Change1 + '\n'
 changeString = changeString + req.body.Change2 + '\n'
 changeString = changeString + req.boyd.Change3 + '\n'
 ....
```

After this I am inserting this field to my database. This is working perfectly fine and I can go in the database and copy the field value into a notepad and see the line changes:

```
sdsdsds
sdsdsds
asdasdsadasdasdas
```

In another page of my website I am pulling the details from the same field and adding it to a table but instead of new lines I am getting

```
sdsdsds sdsdsds asdasdsadasdasdas
```

To add to my table I am doing

```
`<tr>        
     <td>${item.Name}</td>
     <td>${item.Time}</td>
     <td>${item.Description}</td>
 </tr>`
```

If I `console.log` the item description I can see the line changes

The line changes somehow disappear when I add in the HTML.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps try to CSS mark the element that contains line break characters with

```
white-space: pre-line
```

or with

```
white-space: pre-wrap;
```

For example like this:

```
<span style="white-space: pre-line">${item_here}</span>
```

Answer (score 3):

HTML parser will ignore whitespace characters (including `\n` newline) in the source code, so you can use `<br/>` tag to create a newline or render your strings inside a `<pre> /*sometex*/ </pre>`.